# Return SELECT statement if result is between two values

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregation

I have two tables:

Customers:

```
id  FirstName   LastName    Age     City
----------------------------------------
1        Joey       Blue     40  Goddard
2       Barry      Bonds     50  Gaddard
3        Mike    Schmidt     60       KC
4       Steve      Jones     45 New York
```

Orders:

```
OrderId  OrderDate              CustomerID  ProductID
-----------------------------------------------------
      1 2019-08-06 12:10:02.270          1          1
      2 2019-08-06 12:10:33.690          2          1
      3 2019-08-06 12:10:44.970          2          2
      4 2019-08-06 12:10:51.910          1          1
      5 2019-08-06 12:10:52.210          1          1
      6 2019-08-06 12:10:52.657          1          1
      7 2019-08-06 12:10:53.067          1          1
      8 2019-08-06 12:11:17.340          2          1
      9 2019-08-06 12:11:23.963          2          2
     10 2019-08-06 12:11:32.063          3          2
     11 2019-08-06 12:11:38.503          3          1
     12 2019-08-06 12:11:38.790          3          1
     15 2019-08-17 19:51:45.070          2          1
     16 2019-08-17 19:52:14.207          2          2
     17 2019-08-17 19:52:14.540          2          2
     18 2019-08-17 19:52:14.923          2          2
     19 2019-08-17 19:52:31.240          1          2
     20 2019-08-17 19:52:37.363          1          2
     21 2019-08-17 19:52:38.860          1          2
     22 2019-08-17 19:52:39.213          1          2
     23 2019-08-17 19:52:39.613          1          2
     24 2019-08-17 19:52:39.997          1          2
     25 2019-08-17 19:52:40.360          1          2
```

I am trying to return any customer's FirstName and Order count for anyone who has between 4 and 8 orders.

I can join the tables and count the number of orders using:

```
SELECT 
    Cu.FirstName, COUNT(Od.CustomerID) AS 'Customer Orders'
FROM
    Customer AS Cu
INNER JOIN 
    Orders AS Od ON Cu.id = Od.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    Od.CustomerID, Cu.FirstName
ORDER BY 
    [Customer Orders] DESC
```

which returns the output:

```
FirstName   Customer Orders
----------------------------
     Joey                12
    Barry                 8
    Mike                  3
```

But I can't get BETWEEN to work to just return (so I only get the Customers that have between 4 and 8 orders (so my desired output would be:)

```
FirstName   Customer Orders
---------------------------------
    Barry                 8
```

Comment: Add `HAVING COUNT(Od.CustomerID) BETWEEN 4 AND  8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use having  for filter the result of aggregation  function

```
SELECT Cu.FirstName,COUNT(Od.CustomerID) as 'Customer Orders'
from Customer as Cu
inner join Orders as Od on Cu.id=Od.CustomerID
GROUP BY Od.CustomerID, Cu.FirstName
HAVING COUNT(Od.CustomerID) between 4 and  8 
ORDER BY [Customer Orders] DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Cu.FirstName,COUNT(Od.CustomerID) as 'Customer Orders'
  FROM Customer as Cu
  INNER JOIN Orders as Od on Cu.id=Od.CustomerID
  GROUP BY Od.CustomerID, Cu.FirstName
 HAVING COUNT(Od.CustomerID) between 4 and 8
  ORDER BY [Customer Orders] DESC
```

P.S. We don't know your DBMS so far. For some Database's(such as MySQL) SQL, using aliases within the having clauses is permitted such as `HAVING Customer_Orders between 4 and 8` for `COUNT(Od.CustomerID) as Customer_Orders`